# C# webbrowser control causes flash.ocx error on application exit

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I've built a webbrowser using C# with the webbrowser control.
However every time a page is loaded which contains flash content the application will give an error on exit.
It states that the application may not have worked properly and flash.ocx is missing.
If users don't have flash player it's okay to not load the flash elements.

So the actual question i have is: Is it possible for me to hide/cancel/prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to extend the Webbrowser control class.

Perfect article, that helps you blocking these errors, preventing these errors and editing these errors:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13598/Extended-NET-2-0-WebBrowser-Control